# Do I have to specify dependent plugin version while importing them in RCP Projects. What's the best practice?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have n number of plugins in my RCP product where they are dependent on each other. Is it a good practice to specify their version or without version number while importing them in `dependencies` as Required plugins.

P.S. : If I specify version number, whenever my plug-in version change, I should change each and every plugin where I have added them as dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't have to specify a version. In this case any version will do.

If you specify a single version then that is the **minimum** version required - an exact match is not required.

Finally you can specify a range of values - this gives a minimum and maximum version that is allowed.

If you know that a plug-in requires at least a minimum version of another plug-in you should specify that minimum version. You only need to change the minimum version when you make incompatible changes.

You might specify a maximum version of you think you will be making incompatible changes in future versions.